# Uncommon values from two data frames by rows in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes `df1` and `df2`. First column in both is a customer ID which is an `int`, but other columns contains various string values. I want to produce a new dataframe `df3` that contains, for each customer ID, a set of values found in `df2` but not in `df1`.

Example:

**`df1`**:

```
     v1 v2 v3 v4
cust            
1     A  B  B  A
2     A  A  A  A
3     B  B  A  A
4     B  C  A  A
```

**`df2`**:

```
     v1 v2 v3 v4
cust            
1     A  A  C  B
2     A  A  C  B
3     C  B  B  A
4     C  B  B  A
```

Expected output:

```
cust
1       {C}
2    {B, C}
3       {C}
4        {}
```

Comment: Please do not add images, add the dataframes in a way that can be copied into a Python script.

Comment: @DaniMesejo I am new here. I tried other formate, but it does not work. Hope I will get help from you.

Answer (score 0):

```python
In [2]: df_2 = pd.DataFrame({"KundelID" : list(range(1,11)),
   ...:               'V1' : list('AACCBBBCCC'),
   ...:               'V2' : list('AABBBCCCAA'),
   ...:               'V3' : list('CCBBBBBAAB'),
   ...:               'V4' : list('BBAACAAAAB')})
   ...: df_1 = pd.DataFrame({"KundelID" : list(range(1,11)),
   ...:               'V1' : list('AABBCCCCCC'),
   ...:               'V2' : list('BABCCCCAAA'),
   ...:               'V3' : list('BAAAAABBBB'),
   ...:               'V4' : list('AAAACCCCBB')})

In [3]: df_1
Out[3]: 
   KundelID V1 V2 V3 V4
0         1  A  B  B  A
1         2  A  A  A  A
2         3  B  B  A  A
3         4  B  C  A  A
4         5  C  C  A  C
5         6  C  C  A  C
6         7  C  C  B  C
7         8  C  A  B  C
8         9  C  A  B  B
9        10  C  A  B  B

In [4]: df_2
Out[4]: 
   KundelID V1 V2 V3 V4
0         1  A  A  C  B
1         2  A  A  C  B
2         3  C  B  B  A
3         4  C  B  B  A
4         5  B  B  B  C
5         6  B  C  B  A
6         7  B  C  B  A
7         8  C  C  A  A
8         9  C  A  A  A
9        10  C  A  B  B

In [7]: pd.DataFrame({"KundeID" : df_2.KundelID,
   ...:             'Not-in-df_1' : [','.join([i for i in df_2_ if not i in df_1_]) if [i for i in df_2_ if not i in df_1_] else None for df_1_,df_2_ in zip(df_1.T[1:].apply(np.unique), df_2.T[1:].apply(np.unique))]})
Out[7]: 
   KundeID Not-in-df_1
0        1           C
1        2         B,C
2        3           C
3        4        None
4        5           B
5        6           B
6        7           A
7        8        None
8        9        None
9       10        None
```

Comment: While (judging by the output) this provides and answer, you can make your answer more valuable by providing explanation on how you achieved the result. Perhaps splitting (and explaining) the long line of Python code could help?

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to transform all values in each row into a `set`. Then, we can take the set difference for each customer ID. This avoids loops and list comprehensions:

```
df3 = (
    pd
    .concat([
        df1.reindex(index=df2.index).apply(set, axis=1),
        df2.apply(set, axis=1),
    ], axis=1)
    .apply(lambda r: r[1].difference(r[0]), axis=1)
)
print(df3)
# Out:
cust
1       {C}
2    {B, C}
3       {C}
4        {}
```

**Notes**:

1. The bit `df1.reindex(index=df2.index)` is in case some IDs are absent from `df1` or `df2`).
2. It is trivial to transform the output into something else instead of a `set`. For example `','.join(r[1].difference(r[0]))` as the lambda will make strings.

**Setup**:

For future reference, in order to facilitate a reproducible example, it is a good idea to provide some code that can directly be copy/pasted by SO-ers for a quick start into your problem.

```
df1 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""
1 A B B A
2 A A A A
3 B B A A
4 B C A A
"""), sep=' ', names='cust v1 v2 v3 v4'.split()).set_index('cust')

df2 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""
1 A A C B
2 A A C B
3 C B B A
4 C B B A
"""), sep=' ', names='cust v1 v2 v3 v4'.split()).set_index('cust')
```

Answer (score 0):

You transform each dataframe into a Series of sets, then perform a set operation across the Series, leveraging the [intrinsic data alignment](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/dsintro.html#intro-to-data-structures) from pandas Series:

```
df2.apply(set, axis=1) - df1.apply(set, axis=1)
```

Output:

```
cust
1       {C}
2    {C, B}
3       {C}
4        {}
dtype: object
```

---

If you want the [symmetric difference](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#set) across datasets (*i.e.* elements in either the set or other but not both), then it's better using `pd.concat`:

```py
dfs = [df1, df2]
pd.concat([df.apply(set, 1) for df in dfs], 1).apply(lambda x: x[0]^x[1], 1)
```

where 1 here stands for `axis=1`. Also, replacing `x[0]^x[1]` by `set.symmetric_difference(*x)` should work as well.

Interestingly, `Series_A ^ Series_B` doesn't work as expected, instead (apparently), it returns a bool Series telling us if the returning values from the set operations are **not** empty.